# Is there a canonical list of MySQL defaults which should be changed

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, configuration

I'm setting up a new mysql server as we're building a new app at work.
Most of the developers/operations guys are familiar with mysql.

Many of mysql's settings (eg strict mode) are set badly by default for backwards compatibility.

Is there a widely accepted list of which settings have defaults that are dangerous, confusing or otherwise wrong?

I'd like to avoid things like the string 'hello' being considered equal to the integer zero, for instance.